# Call recording issue in Android

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder, phone-call

I want to implement call recording in my one app, So I have used below questions for reference:

[Android Recording Incoming and Outgoing Calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688444/android-recording-incoming-and-outgoing-calls)

[How To Record Incoming Call in android programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19603162/how-to-record-incoming-call-in-android-programmatically)

I am using below code to record a call

```
recorder.reset();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                       recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
                       recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
```

But I have also try to use different audio source and output format but it's not recording properly
its recording one-sided call sometimes, and when changing to voice_call and voice_communication its not recording calls at all

In some thread, I found that in some devices it's not working properly but I found some apps in play store which works quite good

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appstar.callrecorder

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?